# I would like to play 2 x 4k videos side by side on dual monitors on Linux using ffplay

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, video

I would like to use ffplay (if possible) to play 2 x 4k videos on different (dual) monitors connected to the same Linux (Ubuntu) machine. They are same videos (same in length, etc), just differ in quality.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I think your best option is to play the two [videos side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48366737/4926757) as one wide video, and define the two monitors as [extended](https://askubuntu.com/a/316026). Example for horizontal stacking: `ffplay -f lavfi -i "movie=input1.mp4[v0];movie=input2.mp4[v1];[v0][v1]hstack"`

Comment: What is happening when you try? What have you tried?